# Function is not triggering context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, contextmenu

I created a context menu that's supposed to append a selected item (document in table row) into a separate div. I have a column of checkboxes (corresponding with each document) that does the same thing and works correctly, however I haven't been able to get the context menu functionality to work.

Update: Here's a [link](https://ide.c9.io/tsardines/test-proj) to view the code. I used Cloud9's IDE in order to make use of the local JSON file.

#### Context menu code:

```js
$(".checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc);

$("#add-id").on("click", faveFunc);


function faveFunc(evt) {
    var anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
    switch($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length)
    {
      case 0:
        $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
        break;
      default:
        $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
        break;
    }
  }; // ------------ faveFunc


function newList() {
    let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
    let outputList = $(".populate-faves");

      $(".populate-faves").html("");

      $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(el, x) {
        let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
        let cntxFave = $(".add-id", x);
        let itemText = $(data, el);

        if(cntxFave.is(".add-id")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        } // ----- Not sure if this syntax is right, just copying what I have below

        if(fave.prop("checked")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        }
      });
  }; // ------------ newList
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="custom-menu">
        <li data-action="open" id="open-id">Open Document</li>
        <li data-action="add" id="add-id">Set As Favorite</li>
        <li data-action="email">Email Document</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: When i click on your link it says `You do not have permissions to access this project

`

Comment: [Sorry about that.](https://codeanywhere.com/s/l/Mpa0BIs3q9zo0uxeEB3a8jZZFKakEzvmyeIvm0hMPwvfwygnC5qvL51Lyiv2xnwj) How about now?

Comment: The same `You do not have permissions to access this project `

Comment: https://ide.c9.io/tsardines/test-proj Here's a Cloud9 link. Normally I share code snippets with JSBin/JSFiddle so I'm not used to CodeAnywhere's permissions.

Comment: With this i need to create an account. but have a look at my plugin you may find it usefull or even use it

Answer (score 0):

I made plugin for contextMenu sometimes ago this may help you if you need it

Its easy to use.

```
$(".click").contextMenu(option)

option= {
dataSource:[{text: "", click: ()=>}]
action: "left" // "right" for rightClick and left for click
}
```

```js
(function ($)
{
 $.fn.contextMenu = function (options)
 {
  var settings = $.extend({
   dataSource: [],
   click: function (item) { },
   onLoad: function (settings) { },
   action: "right"
  }, options);
  var container = $(this);
  var ini = false;
  if(settings.action === "right")
   container.attr("title", "Right click to edit");
  function buildContext(e)
  {
   $(".contextMenu").remove();
   if(settings.onLoad)
    settings.onLoad(settings);
   var context = $("<ul class='contextMenu'></ul>");
   $.each(settings.dataSource, function ()
   {
    var x = this;
    var div = $("<li class='contextItem'></li>");
    if(typeof x.text === "string")
     div.html($("<span>" + x.text + "</span>"));
    else
     div.html($("<span></span>").append(x.text));

    (div.find("span"), div).click(function ()
    {
     if(x.click)
      x.click(x);
     else
      if(settings.click)
       settings.click(x);
     context.remove();
    });

    function loadItem(item, parent)
    {
     var li = $("<li class='contextItem'></li>");
     if(typeof item.text === "string")
      li.html($("<span>" + item.text + "</span>"));
     else
      li.html($("<span></span>").append(item.text));

     li.click(function ()
     {
      if(settings.click)
       settings.click(item);
      context.remove();
     });

     if(item.children && item.children.length > 0)
     {
      parent.addClass("hasChildren");
      li.addClass("hasChildren");
      var y = $("<ul class='contextsubItem'></ul>");
      $.each(item.children, function ()
      {
       loadItem(this, y);
      });
      li.append(y);
     }
     parent.append(li);
    }

    if(x.children && x.children.length > 0)
     div.addClass("hasChildren");
    var ul = $("<ul class='contextsubItem'></ul>");
    $.each(x.children, function ()
    {
     loadItem(this, ul);
    });
    if(ul.children("li").length > 0)
     div.append(ul);
    context.append(div);
   });
   var iFrame = undefined;
   try
   {
    iFrame = container.closest("html").parent();
    if(iFrame.length <= 0)
     iFrame = undefined;
   } catch(ee)
   {
    // Ignore
   }
   context.css({
    left: e.pageX - 16,
    top: e.pageY + 25
   });
   if(!iFrame)
    $("body").append(context);
   else
   {
    iFrame.find("body").find(".contextMenu").remove();
    iFrame.find("body").append(context);
    iFrame.find("body").mousedown(function (e)
    {
     var target = $(e.target);
     if(!(target.parent().hasClass("contextItem") || target.hasClass("contextItem") || target.hasClass("contextMenu")))
     {
      context.remove();
      iFrame.find("body").find(".contextMenu").remove();
     }

    });
   }

   context.slideDown("slow");
   context.width(Math.max.apply(Math, $.map(context.find("div"), function (o)
   {
    return o.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   })));
   context.children(".contextItem").css("max-width", context.width() - (context.children(".contextItem").outerWidth(true) - context.width()));
   ini = true;
  }

  $("body").mousedown(function (e)
  {
   var target = $(e.target);
   if(!(target.parent().hasClass("contextItem") || target.hasClass("contextItem") || target.hasClass("contextMenu")))
    $(".contextMenu").remove();

  });

  if(settings.action === "right")
  {
   container.bind("contextmenu", function (e)
   {
    buildContext(e);
    return false;
   });

  } else
  {
   container.bind("click", function (e)
   {
    buildContext(e);
    return false;
   });
  }

  return container;
 };

}(jQuery));

$(".rightClick").contextMenu({
dataSource:[{ text:"Alert", click: (item)=> alert("you clicked on " + item.text) }]
})

$(".click").contextMenu({
dataSource:[{ text:"Alert", click: (item)=> alert("you clicked on " + item.text) }],
action:"left"
})
```

```css
body{ background: #CCC}
ul.contextMenu, .contextMenu .contextsubItem {
    position: fixed !important;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 13em;
    max-width: 26em;
    padding: .25em 0;
    margin: .3em;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    border-radius: .2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    z-index: 999;
    list-style: none;
}

.contextMenu .contextsubItem {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute !IMPORTANT;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.contextMenu .hasChildren::after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #0e0e0e;
    margin-top: -17px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.contextMenu .contextItem {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    color: #4e4d4d;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 99%;
}

    .contextMenu .contextItem > span {
        width: 96%;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        color: #545454;
        border-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 6px 20px;
    }

    .contextMenu .contextItem .fa:before {
        padding-right: 5px;
    }


    .contextMenu .contextItem:hover > span:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #337ab7;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contextMenu .contextItem:hover > .contextsubItem {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }


/*.contextMenu {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}*/


.contextMenu:after, .contextMenu:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 14%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.contextMenu:after {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}

.contextMenu:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="rightClick">right Click</p>

<p class="click">Click</p>
```